# non-community wiki answers or non-community-wiki answers?

Tags: hyphenation

I'm curious about the correct punctuation for this phrase which appears in some stack exchange badges...

"non-community wiki answers"

I initially thought it was referring to wiki answers that were somehow non-community.  This confused me.  It turns out it is referring to answers that aren't community wiki answers.

Am I correct that it should be punctuated "non-community-wiki answers"?

related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309426/non-community-wiki-answers-and-grammar

Comment: What happened to the link to this question? http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101122/hyphenation-of-non-combat-related-injury By the way, does the discussion there help you at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost right.  When joining the negative modifier ("non") to a two-word term, you need to keep the two-word term connected by a hyphen, but use an *en dash* to connect the "non"

- non–community-wiki answer

Comment: Thanks - is there a more general rule, or is this specific for "non"?

Comment: I think the preferred treatment here is style-guide specific. For example, if you follow _The Chicago Manual of Style_, the normal way to handle _noncommunity_ as a simple adjective is closed up, no hyphen. So simply by inserting a hyphen between the prefix and the stem and another hyphen between the resulting word and _wiki_ ("non-community-wiki") indicates that the prefix _non-_ applies to the entire compound modifier and not just to _community_. In that case, replacing the first hyphen with an en dash is unnecessary. However, under different style guidelines, the en dash may be appropriate.

Comment: ... _Chicago_ deems the en dash essential in prefixes associated with open compound modifiers, as for example in "pre–Civil War writing."